# how to filter downloaded html page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webclient

i download html page with this code

```
public void getpage()
        {Uri u=new Uri("http://www.vaktija.ba/");
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCallback2);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(u);
        }

        private void DownloadStringCallback2(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            data.Text = e.Result;
        }

        private void but_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            getpage();
        }
```

i want to filter it how can i do that .I mean i just want to have the information not tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing HTML isn't always the easiest thing to do, my suggestion is to use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

---

Another solution could be to use `Regex.Replace`, but it requires the HTML to be completely valid and produces a kind of rough result:

```
//Replace all <tags> with empty string
data.Text = Regex.Replace(e.Result, "<[^>]*>", "");
```

Comment: Here is a [tutorial on how to use the Html Agility Pack aswell](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx)